# Root cause of an "Invalid object name: dbo.etc" error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing some maintenance programming on a fairly large project, which was started by someone who's now left the company...

I've just backed up one of the company's databases, and then reattached it to our test server. That much appears to be working okay.

I then go through the program's usual login procedure, and that part also appears to work.

However, once I get to a point in the program where it needs to execute a stored procedure, I get back an error telling me `Invalid object name 'Informix.dbo.customer'`.

Running the same function on the original database works fine, and returns the data I expect to see.

Explanations for similar errors I've found seem to refer to Schemas, but that's where things get a little odd. The original database doesn't obviously *have* any Schemas; In its "Security" folder it just has a "Users" folder, containing dbo, and a "Roles" folder, containing the "Database Roles" folder, with the usual db_owner, etc. stuff, and an empty folder named "Application Roles".

The Security folder on the backed-up-and-restored database is full of all kinds of crap. Three users in addition to dbo, a "Schemas" folder, "Certificates" folder, two encryption key folders... I can't delete any of these.

From my limited understanding of the SQL login system, the user I'm logging in as is getting non-dbo-permissions from this collection of random crap, and so is being denied access to the parts of the database owned by dbo.

For my own understanding, what is the core of the problem that's throwing up these `Invalid object name` errors? And for practical matters, what can I do to rectify this situation and actually have the program I'm using work on the test database in the same way as it does on the live one?

Comment: Does the restored database have the same name as the production one? Is it possible that the database name is hard coded into the application?

Comment: Sorry, meant to make that point and then forgot. I have tested the stored procedure from within SQL Server Management Studio using the Execute Stored Procedure function and the stored procedure works on the original database, and not on the new one. The database name is the same, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're executing a procedure (SomeProc) in a database (SomeDB) and it's giving the error `Invalid object name 'Informix.dbo.customer'`? That simply means that SomeProc cannot find an object called "customer" in a schema called "dbo" in a database called "Informix". There are several possible reasons for this:

1. The object doesn't exist, possibly because the schema and/or database don't exist
2. The object exists, but the user running the procedure doesn't have permission to even see it
3. The object exists, but the database is case-sensitive and some part of the name doesn't match the name in your code

You'll need to investigate more to find out what the cause is in your case, but as a complete guess, your production server has both the Informix and SomeDB databases, but your test server has only SomeDB?

Finally, when posting questions please always include your SQL Server version (2000/2005/2008) and edition (Express, Standard, Enterprise); they can be very important when talking about schemas and permissions, because features and behaviour can be different.

Comment: Well, my understanding's not quite that bad but I prefer to have everything laid out for me for a better understanding of where I'm having a problem. Problem turned out to be that I thought Informix was a database connection method rather than a specific database and so had *weird* misconceptions about the information I was getting. Should all be fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with the owner of the object (SP in your case).
Check the owner in SQL management studio