# Bit confused with Entity Framework model-to-table convention

Tags: entity-framework

I have this model:

```
public class LkUpTitleModel
{
    [Key]
    public int TitleID { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = " * Has been left empty")]
    [DisplayName("Title")]
    [Remote("LkUpTitle", "Treeview", AdditionalFields = "TitleID", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = " * Already exists")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Tied into this db context

```
namespace MyWork.DAL
{
    public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataBaseContext() : base("name = constring")
        {}

        public DbSet<LkUpGenderModel> vwLkUpGender { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LkUpTitleModel> vwLkUpTitle { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller:

```
public DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext();
```

This is the class in the function for the remote validation

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LkUpTitle(string Title, int? TitleID)
{
    if (TitleID == null)
    {
        TitleID = 0;
    }

    var title = (from g in db.vwLkUpTitle where g.TitleID != TitleID select g).ToList();

    return Json(!title.Any(x => x.Title.ToUpper() == Title.ToUpper()));
}
```

When it runs and tries the validation I get the below error.  Not sure why it is looking for dbo.LkUpTitleModel and not dbo.vwLkUpTitle

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Invalid object name 'dbo.LkUpTitleModel'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.LkUpTitleModel'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 135:            }
>      Line 136:
>      Line 137:            var title = (from g in db.vwLkUpTitle where g.TitleID != TitleID select g).ToList();
>      Line 138:
>      Line 139:            return Json(!title.Any(x => x.Title.ToUpper() == Title.ToUpper()));
>
> Source File: >C:\Users\RLewis\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\Orwell\OrwellFrontEnd\Controllers\TreeviewController.cs    Line: 137
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.LkUpTitleModel'.]
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2508250
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +81
>         System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +606
>         System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4157
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +369
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2047
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +394
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +240
>         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
>         System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +9
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>         System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +355
>         System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +167
>         System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +37
>
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +112
>         System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +738
>         System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6() +97
>         System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
>         System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +155
>         System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189
>         System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +280
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +11
>         System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45
>         System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
>         System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>         OrwellFrontEnd.Controllers.TreeviewController.LkUpTitle(String Title, Nullable`1 TitleID) in C:\Users\RLewis\Source\Workspaces\Workspace\Orwell\OrwellFrontEnd\Controllers\TreeviewController.cs:137
>         lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +151
>         System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>         System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>         System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +225
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +26
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>        System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>        System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>         System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>         System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>         System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>         System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>         System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>         System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>         System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9720041
>         System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: do you have a table in your database named "LkUpTitleModel" ?

Comment: Yeah. Most likely, you need to add a new migration and update your database.

Comment: here is some useful links:

[invalid-object-name-dbo-item][1]

[invalid-object-name-dbo-userroles][2]

[root-cause-of-an-invalid-object-name-dbo-etc-error][3]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729159/invalid-object-name-dbo-item
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725804/invalid-object-name-dbo-userroles
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967800/root-cause-of-an-invalid-object-name-dbo-etc-error

Comment: Hi, there is no table dbo.LkUpTitleModel and I don't want there to be either.  Based on the code I would expect it to look for vwLkUpTitle which does exist.

I can't work out why it is looking for the model name and not the table.

Comment: @JQuery why should it look for `vwLkUpTitle` when you named the class `LkUpTitleModel` ? The *convention* is to match classes and tables by name. You can specify a different table with the [TableAttribtue](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/table-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

EF is matching DBSet and tables by Model name, that means if your DbSet is type of "LkUpTitleModel" then it will be looking for table named "LkUpTitleModel". If you want it to work properly change DbSet type from "LkUpTitleModel" to "vwLkUpTitle".

Comment: That's *not* necessary or a good idea. You can specify the table or view name with a `Table` attribute